# How to declare dependency scope for a local plugin?

Tags: grails

I want to install `my-plugin.zip` with a certain dependency. How can I do this?

This doesn't seem to work inside `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
runtime '/path/to/my/plugin.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin is already packaged as `zip` then it can be referred as any other Grails plugin in `BuildConfig.groovy`. You just need to keep note of 2 things:

- Plugin Name [Generally `MyPlugin` app would have plugin name as `my-plugin`]
- Plugin Version

Then BuildConfig would look like:-

```
//BuildConfig.groovy
plugins{
    runtime ':my-plugin:0.1' 
    //compile ':my-plugin:0.1'
}
```

When plugin is packaged it will be available in `cached-installed-plugins` inside `$Userhome/.grails/<version>` by default. Also, by default the group is `org.grails.plugins`. In order to test for `compile`, `build` and/or `test` configurations, try to change as above and run a `dependency-report` to see the plugin available in corressponding configurations.

**Alternative:**
There is another "**soon-to-be-deprecated**" approach to install your plugin.
`grails install-plugin <path/to/YourPlugin.zip>`

will install the plugin in the application in `default, compile, runtime` configurations. I would not suggest this approach as `install-plugin` is going to be deprecated.

Comment: @zoran119 Which version of Grails do you use? I tested in 2.2.0 and it works great for me. If you are using Grails 2.3.0.M1 release, it uses aether for dependency resolution.

Comment: @zoran119 It does not put in ivy-cache but adds to `cached-installed-plugins` inside `$Userhome/.grails/<version>`. On the other hand have you tried to publish it to local maven repo if you have any using [release](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-release/docs/manual/guide/maven.html#mavenCache) plugin?